# SpriteKit Swift make an entire scene darker, then change it back

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene, sknode

Is there any way to make an entire scene, including all of its children nodes (not just the background color) darker in color? I am looking for an effect similar to that of this code:

```
node.color = SKColor.blackColor()
node.colorBlendFactor = 0.25
```

The above code shades the `node` a darker color, while keeping the original colors (except that those colors are just darker) and detail.
However, as far as I can tell, this code doesn't work on scenes, it only works on `SKSpriteNode`. Is there any way to darken a whole scene? The answer could be some sort of filter, a special way of colorizing a scene, or maybe there is just no way. Anything helps!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I need to do something similar to what you are asking, I simply add a `SKSpriteNode` on top of everything else as follows:

```
let dimPanel = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: self.size)
dimPanel.alpha = 0.75
dimPanel.zPosition = 100
dimPanel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
self.addChild(dimPanel)
```

Just make sure the panel's `zPosition` is greater than everything you want to make dimmer.

This way, you can also use the `SKAction.colorizeWithColor` to change the panel to whatever color you want.

To add the panel and then remove it, you could start the alpha at 0, then do:

```
dimPanel.runAction(SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(0.75, duration: 3),
    SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(3)
]))
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a pretty easy and effective way to solve the problem. I guess I was overthinking it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

> The answer could be some sort of filter...

Indeed. While [@TrentSartain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34385834/957768) is quite practical, it's not the only way. `SKScene` inherits from [`SKEffectNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEffectNode_Ref/index.html), so you can apply a Core Image filter (or filter chain) to the entire scene as a way to darken it or add other visual effects.

Once you get into [Core Image filters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html), you have all kinds of options for darkening — you can get a different effect from ramping the parameters to `CIExposureAdjust` than with `CIToneCurve`, for example. Or you could combine several filters, so your scene (for example) fades to grayscale and blurs as it darkens.

Note: there are no `SKAction`s for animating Core Image filters, but you can change the parameters of a `CIFilter` object over time in your `update` function or a [`customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:) block.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I think I'm going to stick with the simpler option. It's all I need for now. I will keep core image filters in mind later on though if I ever need something more complex.